# Strange crash after entering the background?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, crashlytics

I got a few of these crashes (from Crashlytics), which I can't understand.

Anyone can understand what it is about?

I can see it happens after `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Does it mean it crashes after the app went into the background?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181b9db90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1825314a4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1548
2  CoreFoundation                 0x182406788 _CFXNotificationPost + 368
3  Foundation                     0x182e0e89c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
4  UIKit                          0x18791f124 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 320
5  UIKit                          0x1879ef5e4 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128
6  UIKit                          0x18791ef90 -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 100
7  UIKit                          0x18791f514 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 700
8  UIKit                          0x18792f990 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 448
9  UIKit                          0x18791961c __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 152
10 UIKit                          0x1879192a4 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 712
11 FrontBoardServices             0x183ec77ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
12 FrontBoardServices             0x183ec7618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
13 FrontBoardServices             0x183ec79c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1824dd124 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1824dcbb8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1824da8b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
17 CoreFoundation                 0x182404d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
18 GraphicsServices               0x183cec088 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x1876d9f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
20 Trenìt!                       0x1000f32e4 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x181fa28b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Does it occur when you simply "press the home button" (with actual home button on device or with the command on simulator) or when you exit multitasking? This happens normally if exiting multitasking.

Comment: I am not really sure when it happens. I haven't been able to reproduce it. This log is from Crashlytics.

Comment: It would be of your best interest to try to reproduce it. Run it on the simulator, hit command-shift-h twice, and swipe your app up to get it out of multitasking. If it crashes (try this multiple times and eventually it will), compare the crash logs and see if they're the same.

Comment: Do you stop tasks on entering background? Like download?

Comment: @Quver, no I am not doing anything like that

Comment: @DanieleB any register for notification?

Comment: You guys solved it?

Comment: It was solved by itself, either by GoogleAnalytics (which was the library causing it) or by Crashlytics itself